# How does HTML process the Esc key versus other key

Tags: javascript, html

In this line of code, the ACCESSKEY attribute yields the expected result:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="bDism" name="bDism" onclick="MyProc()" ACCESSKEY=&#97>
```

(other lowercase letters than a work too — haven't tried them all!). When you press ALT a MyProc is called.

Now, this one does not work

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="bDism" name="bDism" onclick="MyPro()" ACCESSKEY=&#27>
```

Could someone please explain why? (In the same form I also have an OK button with ACCESSKEY=&#10 — which is LF, i.e. Enter, which works although LF is a control character just as ESC is).

Comment: in the second line you wrote: onclick="MyPro()"   , shouldnt that be MyPro'c' ?

Comment: @Graviton — Yes, you are right: this mistake stems from the fact that the original line has been "edited" from French to English to allow most users to get the hang of it. Nevertheless, however sharp your eye is, this mistake has no bearing on the case. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The specifications do not define what characters may appear as `accesskey` attribute values and what the exact functionality is. In practice, browsers support a limited set of values, typically letters and digits, in varying ways; see [MDN on `accesskey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes).

Originally intended to promote accessibility, the `accesskey` attribute has generally become a problem rather than part of a solution, partly due to incompatible implementations and due to its interference with other uses of keyboard shortcuts. See e.g. a WebAIM page on [Keyboard Accessibility](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey).

If you have some special need for keyboard commands in HTML, then using JavaScript to process keyboard events is probably a more successful approach.

Comment: Very good: your explanation is quite clear and I shall turn to JS. Thank you Jukka.